# how to apply effect (Pixelate effect) in camera preview in android camera application

Tags: android, canvas, android-camera, pixelate

I'm working on android camera application and I want to apply this pixelate layer in my camera preview?? Kindly help!

```
bitmap = Pixelate.fromAsset(
          getAssets(), "a3.png",
          new PixelateLayer.Builder(PixelateLayer.Shape.Square)
                 .setResolution(32)
                 .build(),
          new PixelateLayer.Builder(PixelateLayer.Shape.Circle)
                 .setResolution(32)
                 .setOffset(15)
                 .build(),
          new PixelateLayer.Builder(PixelateLayer.Shape.Circle)
                 .setResolution(32)
                 .setSize(26)
                 .setOffset(13)
                 .build(), 
          new PixelateLayer.Builder(PixelateLayer.Shape.Circle)
                 .setResolution(32)
                 .setSize(18)
                 .setOffset(10)
                 .build(),
          new PixelateLayer.Builder(PixelateLayer.Shape.Circle)
                 .setResolution(32)
                 .setSize(12)
                 .setOffset(8)
                 .build()
  );
```

Comment: I don't think that those effects will work fast enough to make a preview smooth. But in general you need to capture every frame of camera preview, process it with your `Pixelate`, and show of some view.

Comment: Can u suggest some link related about that?

Comment: just find how to `get bitmap from Camera preview android`, then process that bitmap and do what you find continuously in a separete thread, setting each bitmap into an ImageView for example. This would be a good start, then you can start optimizing code for it to work faster